# SWIFT: Dictionary not displaying in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I'm attempting to display a dictionary in the following format in a tableView (storyboard shown below):

```
var guestList = ["Event 1": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2", "Guest 3"], "Event 2": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"], "Event 3": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"], "Event 4": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"]]
```

[image]

The data gets added to the objectArray variable successfully, but for some reason, none of the guests are showing in the table (see screenshot below):

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class RSVPTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var guestList = [String : [String]]()
let eventList = ["Hindu", "Reception", "Sangeet", "Tibetan"]

struct Objects {

    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
}

var objectArray = [Objects]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for event in eventList { guestList[event] = [String]() }

    let query = PFQuery(className:"GuestList")
    query.whereKey("Family", equalTo: "Family1")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let family = objects {

                print(family)

                for guest in family {

                    for event in self.eventList {


                        if let invited = guest.valueForKey("\(event)Invite") as? Bool {

                            if invited {

                                self.guestList[event]!.append(guest.valueForKey("GuestName") as! String)


                            }
                        }
                    }


                }

                print(self.guestList)
                for (key, value) in self.guestList {
                    print("\(key) -> \(value)")

                self.objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                print(self.objectArray)

            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }

    }




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return objectArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return objectArray[section].sectionName
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell


}

}
```

**SOLUTION:** 
I added self.tableView.reloadData() in my viewDidLoad and it worked.

Comment: A dictionary is probably the wrong backing data container for a table view, use arrays instead. Or even better use some custom class to contain the data: create a Event class which can contain an array of Guests. Make your TableViewDelegate contain a array of Events and everything should be quite self-explanatory.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks, I'm not sure how I would do that.  I am retrieving multiple guests for multiple events.  From other research, the recommendation was to use a dictionary.  I am open to other suggestions, which will help make my solution better.

Comment: Because in the other questions you did not mention the tableview. Typical case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Use breakpoints to see if your datsource methods are being called and, if so, what values they return.

Comment: @PhillipMills, I did what you said, and the issue seems to be that the "guestList" and "objectArray" arrays which are being populated in viewDidLoad have no values when the tableView functions are called.  As shown above, when I print objectArray (or guestList) in viewDidLoad, the values are as they should be, but for some reason, outside of viewDidLoad., they have no values.

Comment: Are your datasource methods being called before `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` completes?

Comment: @PhillipMills, thank you!  I added self.tableView.reloadData() and it worked!  Code has been updated.